# Excel formula to get response time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel where I save an input time of a query and the output time of the query - i.e. when I receive it and when I handle it.

I want to calculate the my response time. What is the right formula?

Comment: How are your input and output times formatted?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the two times entered in cells as proper Excel datetimes then you can simply subtract the starting datetime from the ending datetime.

If starting time is in cell A1 and ending time is in cell B1 then you can calculate difference in C1 with:

```
=B1-A1
```

Excel datetimes are represented as the real numbers with 1 being 01-01-1900.

Depending on your typical response time, you might choose to format the result as hh:mm:ss or as fractions of days. You can use inbuilt and custom number formats to achieve the result you want.

Note: If you do not enter the starting and ending time in a format that Excel understands as datetimes then they will be treated as text and you won't be able to apply the formula I have shown.